# Jquery get mysql values as array

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, arrays

I cant seem to get this right even with all my googling.

I have a mysql table, i need the values from the one column to be returned to my jquery script like this :

```
 array = 123, 556, 553, 542, 4322...
```

I either get it like this:

```
array = "123""556""553""542""4322"...
```

or like this

```
[{"FB_ID":"123"}, {...
```

how can i achieve this with php or jquery?

heres my current code which turned out to look like the last one.

```
$connection = mysql_connect("$host", "$username", "$password") or die(mysql_error()); 

$sql = "SELECT FB_ID FROM `database`.`players` WHERE recieved = '1'";
$result =mysql_query($sql);


$rows = array();
while($r = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    $rows[] = $r;
  }

echo json_encode($rows);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try casting to int:

```
$rows[]=(int)$r['FB_ID'];
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want it like this:

```
[123, 556, 553, 542, 43222, ...]
```

do this:

```
$rows = array();
while($r = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    $rows[] = $r['FB_ID'];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Need to specify a key to fetch it's value.

```
while($r = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    $rows[] = $r['FB_ID'];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In your php page

```
header("Content-type: application/json"); 
$arr = array(123, 556, 553, 542, 4322);
echo json_encode($arr);
```

And in the jquery

```
$.ajax({
url:'yoururl',
type:'post',
dataType:'json',
success:function(result){
  var response    = JSON.stringify(result); 
  res             = JSON.parse(response);
  console.log(res);
}
});
```